Problem with finding tangent lines to an hyperbola

Given the point $Q(0,6)$ and the hyperbola of equation $$\frac{(x-\frac{1}{2})^2}{a^2}-\frac{(y-1)^2}{b^2} =1$$ $$a=-1+\sqrt{29}/2,b=\sqrt{-2+\sqrt{29}}$$ In the figure it's clear that there are four lines that pass through $Q$ and intersect the hyperbola once: Two tangents and two secants (parallel to the asymptotes). I want to find only the tangents, so my proffesor recomended me to do this: write the system consisting of the equation of the hyperbola and the equation of a generic line that passes through $Q$, $y=mx+6$, then solve for $y$ in terms of $x$ on the equation of the line and sustitute $y$ on the other equation. I'm left with a second degree equation in the variable $x$ which must have zero discriminant. But then there are only two solutions for $m$ (the slope), how is that possible?

Making the discriminant of that $x$-equation vanish effectively gives the condition for the line to touch the hyperbola in a "double-point", so it corresponds to the tangent scenario. A secant line parallel to the asymptote crosses the hyperbola at just one (finite) point, which is a different interaction.

Another take on what @Blue said -- think about what happens as you approach the asymptote: the second solution gets bigger and bigger; in other words, it's more like the discriminant becomes infinite rather than zero.

The coefficient of $x^2$ in the quadratic equals $(-4 b^2+4 a^2 m^2)$. Set this equal to zero.

When you put the discriminant zero it is the condition for the roots of a quadratic equation to be equal, but in case of secants that intersect hyperbola at only point the case is different they do have 2 solutions it is just that one of the solutions approaches $\infty$ or $-\infty$ so the coefficient of $x^2$ would become zero for those values of $m$. If you want to calculate their values instead of putting discriminant as $0$ try putting coefficient of $x^2$ as $0$.
HERE IS AN EXPLANATION FOR WHY IT WORKS
while equating $2$ polynomials lets suppose one of the roots is $\infty$ the coefficient of highest degree term must be $0$
Take $n$ degree equations
$$a_0x^n+a_2x^{n-1}\dots+a_n=b_0x^n+b_2x^{n-1}\dots+b_n$$
Divide the equation with $x^n$:
$$a_0+\frac{a_2}x\dots+\frac{a_n}{x^n}=b_0+\frac{b_2}x\dots+\frac{b_n}{x^n}$$
put limit $x\to\infty$
$$\implies a_0=b_0$$
Similarly for $-\infty$
So the highest degree term cancels out if one of the roots approaches $\infty$ or $-\infty$

Given a hyperbole $\mathscr{H}$ and a line $\mathscr{L}_{p_0}$ passing by $p_0$ as
$$
\cases{
\mathscr{H}\to  \frac{(x-\frac{1}{2})^2}{a^2}-\frac{(y-1)^2}{b^2} =1\\
\mathscr{L}_{p_0}\to y - y_0 = m (x - x_0)
}
$$
if them are tangent at $(x,y)$ then at this point, after eliminating $y$ we have
$$
p(x) = 4 a^2 - b^2 + 4 a^2 b^2 + 4 b^2 x - 8 a^2 m x - 4 b^2 x^2 + 
 4 a^2 m^2 x^2 + 8 a^2 m x_0 - 8 a^2 m^2 x x_0 + 4 a^2 m^2 x_0^2 - 8 a^2 y_0 + 8 a^2 m x y_0 - 8 a^2 m x_0 y_0 + 4 a^2 y_0^2
$$
This polynomial is the resulting intersection set between $\mathscr{H}$ and $\mathscr{L}_{p_0}$.  Now if they are also tangent, then it is mandatory that $p(x)$ have a double root at the tangency point $x_1$ or
$$
p(x) = c_1(x-x_1)^2,\ \ \ \ \forall x
$$
This is equivalent to
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{rcl}
 4 a^2 b^2+4 a^2 m^2 x_0^2-8 a^2 m x_0 y_0+8 a^2 m x_0+4 a^2
   y_0^2-8 a^2 y_0+4 a^2-b^2-c_1 x_1^2 & = & 0 \\
 -8 a^2 m^2 x_0+8 a^2 m y_0-8 a^2 m+4 b^2+2 c_1 x_1 & = & 0  \\
 4 a^2 m^2-4 b^2-c_1  & = & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right.
$$
In our case, with $a=-1+\sqrt{29}/2,b=\sqrt{-2+\sqrt{29}}$ it reads:
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{rcl}
 -c_1 x_1^2-60 \sqrt{29}+645  & = & 0\\
 2 c_1 x_1+\left(330-40 \sqrt{29}\right) m+4 \sqrt{29}-8  & = & 0\\
 -c_1+\left(33-4 \sqrt{29}\right) m^2-4 \sqrt{29}+8  & = & 0\\
\end{array}
\right.
$$
now eliminating $\{c_1,x_1\}$ we have
$$
\left(276311935 \sqrt{29}-1489099245\right) m^2+\left(557106835-103056605 \sqrt{29}\right)
   m-362639016 \sqrt{29}+1964963132=0
$$
then
$$
m = \{-2.4745911898422115, 4.386757590861432\}
$$

